# Update column value after some validation on it

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a scenario where i need to update the value of a column or say append !

Below is test table and data

```
create table test (rsrc_nm varchar2(50), parm varchar2(400)); 

insert into test values ('HLRCamelProfileBasic','resource_code:7|resource_type:HLR_Camel_Profile|Priority:1|');
insert into test values ('HSSUSERProfileBasic','resource_code:3|resource_type:HSS_User_Profile|Priority:1|'); 
insert into test values ('HSSUSERProfileBasic','resource_code:3|resource_type:HSS_User_Profile|Priority:2|');
insert into test values ('HSSUSERProfileBasic','resource_code:3|resource_type:HSS_User_Profile|Priority:1|');
insert into test values ('HLRBaseProfileBasic','resource_code:1|resource_type:HLR_Base_Profile|Priority:2|');
insert into test values ('HLRBaseProfileBasic','resource_code:1|resource_type:HLR_Base_Profile|Priority:3|');
```

Here we have 2 columns of a staging table in which rsrc_nm and parm are given what i have to do is i need to update or append the rsrc_nm column for parm coulmn where the last value i.e. priority is changing from 1 to 2 for same rsrc_nm.

For example

```
rsrc_ nm -- HSSUSERProfileBasic      parm -- resource_code:3|resource_type:HSS_User_Profile|Priority:1|                     
rsrc_ nm -- HSSUSERProfileBasic      parm -- resource_code:3|resource_type:HSS_User_Profile|Priority:2|
```

Here we have same parm priority but the values are different and i need to insert these values into another table for which i need to separate all PIPE values so while i insert it in the table it gives me error for unique constraint because that table table have 3 columns

```
RSRC_NM                                   PARM                  VAL
-------------------------------        --------------            ----------------
HSSUSERProfileBasic            Priority                  1
HLRCamelProfileBasic            Priority                    1
HLRBaseProfileBasic              Priority                    2
```

And on this table we have primary key on first two columns which enforce unique constraint also so i can not insert " HLRCamelProfileBasic " rsrc_nm for parm " Priority " because it fails in uniqueness.

So i find a solution to overcome this if i can append or update the rsrc_nm HLRCamelProfileBasic to " HLRCamelProfileBasic_1 " for " Priority:1 " and HLRCamelProfileBasic_2 for " Priority:2 " and so on for all RSRC_NM in Staging table.

My solution --

```
declare

  cursor c1 is select * from RSRC_SVC_MAPPING where parm_entry like '%Priorit%'; 

  parm_entry_length number;
  l_value     varchar2(100);
  parm_name   varchar2(100);
  parm_val    varchar2(100); 
  l_c1       c1%rowtype;
  l_cnt      number := 0;
  l_rsrc_nm   varchar2(100); 
begin

  open c1;
  loop
  fetch c1 into l_c1;

   parm_entry_length := length(l_c1.Parm_Entry) -   length(replace(l_c1.Parm_Entry,'|',''));  
     for i in 1 .. parm_entry_length loop 
         select regexp_substr(l_c1.Parm_Entry,'[^|]+',1,i) into l_value from dual;   
        select regexp_substr (l_value, '[^:]+', 1, 1) into parm_name from dual;    
         select regexp_substr (l_value, '[^:]+', 1, 2) into parm_val from dual; 
    -- dbms_output.put_line(l_value||' '||parm_name||' '||parm_val||' '||l_c1.resourcename);

   for r in ( select count(*) cnt, resourcename  
     -- into l_cnt , l_rsrc_nm
      from (select count(*), resourcename, parm_entry from RSRC_SVC_MAPPING      where parm_entry like '%Priorit%' group by resourcename, parm_entry) group by resourcename)
      loop
    if r.cnt > 1 
     then
     dbms_output.put_line(l_value||' '||parm_name||' '||parm_val||' '||l_c1.resourcename);
       update RSRC_SVC_MAPPING
          set resourcename = r.resourcename||'_'||l_cnt
       where resourcename  = r.resourcename;
       l_cnt := l_cnt +1;
     end if;
     end loop;
   end loop;
   exit when c1%notfound;
   end loop;

 exception 
   when others then 
   dbms_output.put_line('ERROR OCCURED '||SQLCODE||' '||sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());  
 end;
```

Data which needs to be like after UPDATE is like

```
HSSUSERProfileBasic_1                    resource_code:3|resource_type:HSS_User_Profile|Priority:1|
HSSUSERProfileBasic_2                        resource_code:3|resource_type:HSS_User_Profile|Priority:2|
HLRBaseProfileBasic_2                        resource_code:1|resource_type:HLR_Base_Profile|Priority:2|
HLRBaseProfileBasic_3                       resource_code:1|resource_type:HLR_Base_Profile|Priority:3|
```

Here we have changed the value rsrc_nm column and append it with the value of priority i.e. 1 and 2

target table is like

```
create table target (rsrc_nm varchar2(100), parm varchar2(50), val varchar2(50) constraint tgt_pk primary key (rsrrc_nm, parm));

MY DB is -- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: Are you just trying to use the row with the highest priority for each code/type, insert that, and discard those with lower priorities? Or do you need to take existing rows in the target table into account too? Maybe you can add the before-and-after data for your target table.

Comment: No i need to insert all priority and its does not depends on low or high

Comment: So... changing the resource name for the insert? Just based on what is in test, e.g. just appending the priority value to the name; or also what is already in the target table? Always appending or only if there are duplicates? Bit confused about how the target table will be used but that's another issue. Again, showing before and after data would help.

Comment: See mu edited question i have made something whicg refer to my orginal staging table but still here i am using only two columns which i gave in test table.
Here i am not able to update the resourcename column (rsrc_nm in test table) with the value on priority value but i am able to penetrate in the concerned rows not :)